# Get the name of submit button in PHP

Tags: php, submit, form-submit

How do I get the name of the submit button in PHP?

I got the value of submit button, but I could not find
any code to get the name of the button. Below is the code I have written.

```
<form name="form1"  method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="hello" name="submitbutton">
</form>

<?php
    echo "Value of submit button: " . $_POST['submitbutton'];
    echo "Name of submit button: " . // What should I do here? //;
?>
```

Comment: Isn't submitbutton is your name ? like how do you access an element without id ? In your example you use its name to get value (beats me why). So i don't know what you want to see here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find the name in the $_POST array.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This way you will see everything in the $_POST array.

You can iterate through the array with:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $content) { // Most people refer to $key => $value
   echo "The HTML name: $name <br>";
   echo "The content of it: $content <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`'submitbutton'` is the name of your submit button.
you can get the names of super global $_POST array elements with [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function

```
$postnames = array_keys($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its like any other POST variable, the name will be in the $_POST array. The name is the key in the $_POST array.