# how can i get form data without knowing html element parameter on another page in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a online test application,and invoking question with options on one page. At the end of the test i want to publish score on another page. For that i want all form data on another page, do u hav any idea to get that?

```
<form  name="test" method ="post" action="testfinish.php">
    <input type="submit" name="endtest" value="End Test"/>
    <?php
        $count=4;
        $que = array();
        $que = $userObj->getQue($count);
        $_SESSION['count']=$count;
        foreach($que as $q){ ?>
            <br>
            <div style = "border:2px solid;">
            <div style = "border:2px solid;"><?php echo $q['que']?></div><br>
            <ol>
                <li><input type = "radio" name = "<?php echo $q['que_id']?>" value = "<?php echo $q['a']?>" /> <?php echo $q['a']?></li>
                <li><input type = "radio" name = "<?php echo $q['que_id']?>" value = "<?php echo $q['b']?>" /> <?php echo $q['b']?></li>
                <li><input type = "radio" name = "<?php echo $q['que_id']?>" value = "<?php echo $q['c']?>" /> <?php echo $q['c']?></li>
                <li><input type = "radio" name = "<?php echo $q['que_id']?>" value = "<?php echo $q['d']?>" /> <?php echo $q['d']?></li>
            </ol></div>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

In `testfinish.php`,just use

```
<?php
$result = $_REQUEST;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result); // posted values printed as array 
echo '</pre>';
```

You will find the name of the button in the `$_REQUEST`
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074931/get-the-name-of-submit-button-in-php)

Comment: Better: Use $_REQUEST - for indeed parameters can be transfered in many ways, sometimes mixed. As OP claims he has no further information about the form he has to serve, better cover all your bases.

Comment: @MartinHohenberg Updated my answer.
Actually the form method is `POST`.

Comment: but how can i check that `if(isset($_POST['endtest'])) {...}`

Comment: how can i confirm that all the parameters comes from **form test ** and submitted after clicked on ** endtest ** ?? // think about situation where multiple form submission.

Comment: updated answer.please check.Actually you could find the form value in the `$_REQUEST` array