# PHP Get name value from submit button

Tags: php, forms

I have searched for a solution to this problem, the closest I came was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074931/get-the-name-of-submit-button-in-php), however it does not provide sufficient explanation.

The following button contains BOTH a tournaments name and a tournaments number.

`<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $tournament.$weekNumber ?>"  />`

Tournaments can VARY i.e. have different names & round numbers. When the button is clicked and the form is submitted how do you get the tournament name and round number contained in the button name?

I have tried

`foreach($_POST as $name => $content) {
        //echo "The TOURNAMENT NAME IS: $name <br>";
        $tournament = $name;
    }`

The problem...**it gives me the round number AND tournament name concatenated**....

I could use `substr()` to separate the tournament and round but it wont work since tournament names and round numbers can vary...

**I need BOTH the tournament name and Week Number** which is concatenated in the buttons name `name="<?php echo $tournament.$weekNumber ?>"`

Comment: try name="<?php echo $tournament."*".$weekNumber ?>". then explode using *.

Comment: You can use `[]` to submit an array. This might be a lot easier to handle than splitting a string. E.g. `<button type="submit" name="t1[17]" value="foo">Submit</button>` would result in something like `$_POST['t1'][17] == 'foo'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Separate the name with asymbol and then split.

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $tournament.'_'.$weekNumber ?>"  />

foreach($_POST as $name => $content) {
        //echo "The TOURNAMENT NAME IS: $name <br>";
        list($tournament, $round) = explode('_', $name);
    }
```

Comment: THIS WORKS GREAT. The only problem the round remains concatenated on the tournament name, but round displays perfectly. Example `$tournament = PremeirLeague_5` `$round = 5` How would I get rid of that `_5` concatenated on the tournament name...? thanks

Comment: My bad figured it out simply use `explode()` function

Answer (score 2):

When you concatenate both variables, you can add an unique string that you can use for splitting.

For example

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $tournament.'|-|'.$weekNumber ?>"  />
```

In the PHP code, you can do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $content) {
    //echo "The TOURNAMENT NAME IS: $name <br>";
    list ($tournament, $weekNumber) = explode('|-|', $name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will implement now and provide feedback

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this:

```
<input type="submit" name="tournament[<?php echo $tournament ?>][<?php $weekNumber ?>]"  />
```

and then

```
if (isset($_POST["tournament"]) {
foreach ($_POST["tournament"] as $tournament => $weeks) {
       foreach ($weeks as $round=> $value) {
             //Do stuff
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use hidden value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="tournament" value="<?php echo $tournament ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="weekNumber " value="<?php echo $weekNumber ?>" />

<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $tournament.$weekNumber ?>"  />
```

now you can get both value.